# How can I write a regular expression that matches everything between the first and the last quote?

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to match multiple values between quotes 
(these values can be anything but spaces)
the best I can achieve is to match everything between the first and the last quote

**I already checked many SO answers, yet I cannot make it work**

here is the regex

```
\[\[\[(\w*img\w*)\s(\w*id|url\w*)+="([^"]|.*)"\]\]\]
```

here is the string I try to match (values are numbers but I could have urls or anything similar)

```
[[[img id="37" w="100" h="70"]]]
```

I should get all parameters and their respecting values, but I get only one parameter with the value beeing **37" w="100" h="70**

I know I am close, but this one is tricky

regards

[image]

Comment: I try to stop at the firs quote I find

Comment: Do it in two steps (you do not have much choice in JS): 1) https://regex101.com/r/WVoyjg/1 and then match against Group 2 with 2) https://regex101.com/r/WVoyjg/2

Comment: ok, good idea, I have somewhat a different result on https://www.regextester.com/

Comment: And what about your code? You tagged it with JS tag. It does not matter much what those online regex testers show if you do not know how to apply the pattern in real code.

Comment: Please don't put answers into questions. If you want to add an answer, please [add an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Also please avoid adding your [own tags into the title](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need all the `\w`.
And I also would suggest splitting the task in two parts as suggested in a comment.

However, I also see an [option in doing it in just one step](https://regex101.com/r/AARRdK/2):

```
\[\[\[img(?:\s(\w+)="([^"]+)")?(?:\s(\w+)="([^"]+)")?(?:\s(\w+)="([^"]+)")?\]\]\]
```

This is basically the wrapper `[[[]]]`, a normal character part `img` and then `(?:\s(\w+)="([^"]+)")?` repeated as many times as you expect attributes to appear. `(\w+)` matches the name of the attribute and `([^"]+)` its value.

Comment: I managed to make it work, I had to add a global group to match multiple characters \[\[\[(\w*img\w*)\s((\w*id|url|w|h\w*)="([0-9]+)"\s?)+\]\]\]

Comment: but yours is even better :-)

Comment: this one is killer !! /\[\[\[img(?:\s(?<param1>\w+)="(?<value1>[^"]+)")?(?:\s(?<param2>\w+)="(?<value2>[^"]+)")?(?:\s(?<param3>\w+)="(?<value3>[^"]+)")?\]\]\]/